# How to write python test to connect to rabbitmq?

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, pytest

I am pretty new to python and I want to develop an habit of writing tests before coding but I don't know how to successfully write a test to connect to rabbitmq server. Here is the test I was able to come up with using Flask and pytest

```
class TestVerifyService(BaseTestCase):    

    def test_connect_queue(self):
        """
        Ensure RabbitMQ server is properly configured
        @return:
        @rtype:
        """
        self.assertTrue(os.environ.get('RABBIT_HOST'))
        self.assertTrue(os.getenv('RABBIT_USER'))
        self.assertTrue(os.getenv("RABBIT_PASS"))
```

And this is the function I am testing against:

```
def connect_queue():
    """
    Create a connection to RabbitMQ server
    @return: connection, channel
    """
    rabbit_url = f"amqp://{os.getenv('RABBIT_USER')}:{os.getenv('RABBIT_PASS')}@{os.getenv('RABBIT_HOST')}"
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters(rabbit_url))
    channel = connection.channel()
    return connection, channel
```

Please how do I ensure my test tests properly for the function above? Thank you.

Comment: your code example uses `unittest`, do you want an answer illustrating `pytest` or `unittest`?

Comment: @gold_cy I want an illustration using `pytest`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to write the correct test:

```
def test_connect_queue(self):
    self.assertTrue(os.environ.get('RABBIT_HOST'))
    self.assertTrue(os.getenv('RABBIT_USER'))
    self.assertTrue(os.getenv("RABBIT_PASS"))
    response = connect_queue()
    self.assertTrue(response)
```

Comment: you shouldn't be connecting to the actual service if you are writing unit tests, you should be mocking that functionality

Comment: you can read extensively here --> https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch